# how to remove index path for the radio button in table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here I am having a radio button after making radio button enable then the delete and edit buttons will appear after selecting delete the particular cell was deleting but the preceding row radio button was enabling how to avoid this any help ?

and here is the code for this

```
  @IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
        _ = self.checkIsButtonEnable.index(of: sender.tag)
        if sender.isSelected {

        } else{
            if(chekIndex == nil){
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.append(sender.tag)
                self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                self.addressSelected = true
                tableDetails.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
                tableDetails.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
  func deleteAction(button: UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        self.tableDetails.beginUpdates()
        shippingArray.remove(at:(index?.row)!)
        self.tableDetails.deleteRows(at: [index!], with: .top)
        self.tableDetails.endUpdates()
        tableDetails.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
        self.addressSelected = false
        self.tableDetails.reloadData()
    }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
            tableDetails.isHidden = false
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let arr = shippingArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"] as? String
            cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
            let mobilenumber : Any =  arr["number"] as AnyObject
            cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\(mobilenumber)"
            cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
                cell.editButton.isHidden = false
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            }
            else
            {
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            }
            return cell
        }
```

[image: And image for this is shown below]

Comment: You already set tag value to delete button -> cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row in cellForRowAt. Access that tag value in you delete method and remove values in array using button.tag values

Comment: how to remove I didn't understand exactly ? @AshwiniChougale

Comment: Simple, when you delete row remove that index from selected array also. 
You are deleting data from indexpath.row(eg.3) and reloading. So basically after deleting 3 row queue refreshed and (4 --> 3) 4 index data move to 3 and you'll have  one less item in total.

Comment: just you need to do ->
       
        shippingArray.remove(at:(button.tag))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two line in your delete method.

```
func deleteAction(button: UIButton) {
    let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
    let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    self.tableDetails.beginUpdates()
    shippingArray.remove(at:(index?.row)!)
    self.tableDetails.deleteRows(at: [index!], with: .top)
    self.tableDetails.endUpdates()
    tableDetails.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
    self.addressSelected = false

    **let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: button.tag)
    self.checkIsRadioSelect.remove(at:checkIndex)**

    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Welcome, its mam